# R custom parser function

Tags: r, bigdata

I have data in txt file in this form:

```
col1      col2       col3                 col4        col5

    44       PT-222     My name is John        829302      24.02.14 01.53.51.000000 AM
    11       PT-111     This is not user       8292829     24.02.14 01.40.47.000000 AM
```

I want to stress that this columns are not tab seperated. They are only one or more space seperated. And I col3 and col5 contains data that is composed of space seperated words.

Actually rows are fixed length. To make it clear:

```
44       PT-222     My name                       829302      24.02.14 01.53.51.000000 AM
1         PT-1     This is not user and John      829         24.02.14 01.40.47.000000 AM
```

How can I read that txt file into a table?

Is there any custom seperator function reading 1 line, so that I can override it?

Comment: Is this fixed-width data? The `read.fwf` function might help here. You could use `readLines(..., n=1)` to read just the first line to fine the cut points to use in `read.fwf` if the format changes from file to file.

Comment: No, actually column3 is any lenght sentence. When I parsed it with java, I seperated it by one or more spaces, then, get 1st,2nd, last, and before last elements. The rest is column3.

Comment: There is no such function. You would need to build one using regex expressions. If you have figured out the logic and it works in general then it should be possible to implement.

Comment: So you're saying that column 4 starts at a different character each row? I guess your example didn't make that clear.

Comment: Sorry, I edited to make it clear

Comment: After you've written your own parser, be sure to fire the person that thought this data format was a good idea.

Comment: I think I can make it fixed length data. So every line will be fixed in length. Can I make solution in this case?

Comment: So, I edited the question, so data to be in fixed length. Can it be solved now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the fields are fixed width you can use `read.fwf`.  Otherwise, we can use `read.pattern` in the gsubfn package.  (Below we can replace `text = Lines` with something like `"myfile.dat"` .)  First we read in the column names `cn` separately since they are not in the same format as the data.  Then we skip over the first two lines of the file since the data begins in the third line and we read in the data using an appropriate pattern, `pat`:

```
Lines <- "col1      col2       col3                 col4        col5

    44       PT-222     My name is John        829302      24.02.14 01.53.51.000000 AM
    11       PT-111     This is not user       8292829     24.02.14 01.40.47.000000 AM"

library(gsubfn)
cn <- read.table(text = Lines, nrow = 1, as.is = TRUE)
pat <- "^ *(\\S+) +(\\S+) +(.*\\S) +(\\S+) +(\\S+ \\S+ \\S+) *$"
DF <- read.pattern(text = Lines, pattern = pat, skip = 2,
         col.names = cn, as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
> DF
  col1   col2             col3    col4                        col5
1   44 PT-222  My name is John  829302 24.02.14 01.53.51.000000 AM
2   11 PT-111 This is not user 8292829 24.02.14 01.40.47.000000 AM
```

Note that the pattern we used assumes that no fields are empty.  Any rows that do not match the pattern are silently dropped.  The `skip=2` is optional since the first two rows would be ignored in any case since they do not match the pattern.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: Do you understand the regex-engine well enough to explain why the middle pattern ` +(.*\\S)` doesn't grab more than it does? The patterns at the two ends seem fairly "determinate" but that dot-star "phrase" would seem to be non-specific.

Comment: If the middle pattern grabbed more or less then the subsequent portion of the regex could not match.